# Different history for different terminals

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, bash-history

I would like to have something like "history environment", so for different consoles I can access different histories.

I have different terminals defined, I would like to have for each terminal its own history:

[image]

Comment: Do you need this to survive closing the terminal or opening a new one or do you only need this while the terminal is open? Do you want all commands run in the "Local" terminal, for example, to always be in their own history? So that every time you open a "Local" terminal, you only see commands that were run in such a terminal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by defining different history files for each profile. The history file's name is set by the value of the `HISTFILE` environment variable. Therefore, setting a custom command for each of your terminal profiles which sets this variable to a specific file and then runs `bash` will give you a history for each profile:

[image: screenshot of gnome-terminal preferences showing the custom command]

The command should be:

```
env HISTFILE=/home/terdon/.bash_history.one bash
```

Change `/home/terdon/.bash_history.one` to a name that works on your system, it can be anything you want, but better to have it in your `$HOME`. Then just set a different file for each profile and you should be done.

Comment: Minor detail: I'd go with `env HISTFILE=... bash`, i.e. using `env` exactly what it was designed for, rather than using the much more heavyweight `bash` as the wrapper.

Comment: @egmont duh! Of course! Thank you, should have thought of that myself.